# spring data rest throw nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: spring-data-rest

I am trying to use spring data rest in my project, I prefer to use xml config instead of using spring boot, this is what I am doing:

1. in POM:

   - spring: 4.1.4.RELEASE
   - spring-hateoas: 0.16.0.RELEASE
   - spring-data-rest-webmvc:2.2.2.RELEASE
2. In web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
 
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

3. Repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "testcases", path = "testcases")
public interface ITestCaseRepository extends CrudRepository<TestCase, Long> {
        List<TestCase> findByName(String name);
        
        @Query("SELECT t from TestCase t  WHERE LOWER(t.name) = LOWER(?1) AND t.type = ?2")
        List<TestCase> myFindByNameANDType(String name, TestCaseType type);
        
        List<TestCase> findByNameANDType(String name, TestCaseType type);
        
}
```

When I visit http://localhost:8080/rest, I got this error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.construct([Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;ZLcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/TypeSerializer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/MapSerializer;
```

It describes that the server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

The exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.construct([Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;ZLcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/TypeSerializer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/MapSerializer;
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1287)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

The root cause:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.construct([Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;ZLcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/TypeSerializer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/MapSerializer;
    org.springframework.hateoas.hal.Jackson2HalModule$HalLinkListSerializer.serialize(Jackson2HalModule.java:169)
    org.springframework.hateoas.hal.Jackson2HalModule$HalLinkListSerializer.serialize(Jackson2HalModule.java:109)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:569)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:597)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:118)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1819)
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:231)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:161)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:144)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
    org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.handleReturnValue(ResourceProcessorHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.java:172)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I have no idea what's wrong with code, please help to figure out the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are referencing the wrong version of `com.fasterxml.jackson`

BR

Comment: This is my settings: <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.2</version>, unfortunately not working
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.2</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Try to use Jackson 2.5.1 http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core